# Who are the Buddhas Yet to Come and what Information do we have about them as per Theravada standpoint?

Tags: buddhas

Who are the Buddha's who have got definite prophecy of Buddhahood? What is the description we have about them, their parents, family, disciples and sasana? What are the sources?

Answer (score 2):

There are many schools and teachers in Buddhism. They all contribute to the growing dispersement of Buddhist teaching. The past is full of references to the Buddhas of the past like Shakyamuni Buddha, his closest students, Bodhidharma, Dogen, and all the Buddhist teachers that have come to the west in the last 75 years.
How can we know what tomorrow's flowers will look like and what scent they will carry when they are only seedlings popping out of rocky soil? Just don't know.